# Next button not showing other posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress I have many posts, every page I am showing 5 posts.
Bottom of my page I have next and prev button. When I click one the next button it will go to `/page/2/` link but this page title is showing `Page not found`. And it's not showing other posts in page 2.

My next and prev code :

```
  <div class="prev-next-btn">
             <?php next_posts_link( __( 'next', 'themename' ) ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-next-btn">
                <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'prev', 'themename' ) ); ?>
            </div>
```

My index.php code :

```
   <div class="center-content">
        <ul>
            <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=5'); ?>
            <?php   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <li>

            <div class="date">In
                <?php
                    $category = get_the_category(); 
                    if(!empty($category))
                        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>';

                    ?> 
                    - <?php the_time('d M, Y') ?>
          </div>
            <!--<div class="auther">by <?php the_author(); ?>  <span> - <?php comments_number( 'no comments', 'one comment', '% comments' ); ?> Reply</span></div>-->
            <div class="title clear-both"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
            <div class="details"><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></div>
            <div class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read more</a></div>
            <br>
          </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>
        </div>
          <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { 
                        wp_pagenavi(); 
                    }
                    else {
                ?>  
            <div class="prev-next-btn">
             <?php next_posts_link( __( 'next', 'themename' ) ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-next-btn">
                <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'prev', 'themename' ) ); ?>
            </div>
              <?php } ?>
          </div>
      <?php else : ?>
            404 Nothing here. Sorry.
            <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: Posting the code of the buttons is useless, the button works. The problem could be your query, your permalink structure, an SEO plugin conflict...

Comment: It's impossible to answer this if you only give us this info. We need to complete context, not just a small piece of it

Comment: I just added my full context.Can you please have a look

Comment: could be a .htaccess problem too.

Comment: What is the exact problem in .htaccess. Can you please tell

Comment: What is the solution for this issue?

Comment: You are using `query_posts` which will break pagination and many other stuff of your page

Comment: Also, you do not need a custom query. Why are you using a custom query

Comment: Instead of "query_posts" what can i use for limit the page per posts?

Comment: I will post an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have a few issues here

1. **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. It is slow, reruns queries, breaks and fails silently with pagination and worse of all, it breaks the main query object. If you break the main query object, you break page functions. So, please never use `query_posts`. Mke if it never existed
2. You have replaced the main query loop with a custom query, which you must not do. If you need to show a different amount of posts on a particular page ( not on page templates and a static front page though as this will not work there ), then use `pre_get_posts`. You need to go and read how helpful that action is and how to use it

Remove this line

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=5'); ?>
```

Then add the following in your functions file

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query )
{
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Next', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add below code: I added 'paged' variable and set in `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()`..please see below code:

```
<div class="center-content">
        <ul>
            <?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;   
            query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>5,'paged'=>$paged )); ?>
            <?php   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
          <li>

            <div class="date">In
                <?php
                    $category = get_the_category(); 
                    if(!empty($category))
                        echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>';

                    ?> 
                    - <?php the_time('d M, Y') ?>
          </div>
            <!--<div class="auther">by <?php the_author(); ?>  <span> - <?php comments_number( 'no comments', 'one comment', '% comments' ); ?> Reply</span></div>-->
            <div class="title clear-both"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
            <div class="details"><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></div>
            <div class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read more</a></div>
            <br>
          </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>
        </div>
          <div class="pagination">
                <?php
                global $wp_query;
                    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { 
                        wp_pagenavi(); 
                    }
                    else { echo 'test';
                ?>  
            <div class="prev-next-btn">
             <?php echo next_posts_link( __( 'next', 'themename' ) , $wp_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-next-btn">
                <?php echo previous_posts_link( __( 'prev', 'themename' ) , $wp_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>
              <?php } ?>
          </div>
      <?php else : ?>
            404 Nothing here. Sorry.
            <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: `query_posts` breaks the main query as described in the other answer.

Comment: You broke the main query, so using `$wp_query` is totally useless